# Dart beginner help needed

Tags: dart

```
var a = [{'answers' : [{'text':'Cloud','score':10},],},];

main()
{
  print(a[0]['answers']);
}
```

I want to print number 10 in 'score'
Anyone help me fix code !!!
Thanks first !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is properly null-safety which complains about using the value from `['answers']`. The reason is that the `[]` operator on `Map` returns a nullable type because the result can be `null` in case that the element does not exist in the `Map`.

I have in the following used `!` to promise the compiler that you are sure that the element does exist in the `Map` so it stops complaining. But it will insert a check on runtime and crash your application in case the returned value is `null`:

```
var a = [
  {
    'answers': [
      {'text': 'Cloud', 'score': 10},
    ],
  },
];

void main() {
  print(a[0]['answers']![0]['score']); // 10
}
```